# Find second/third/fourth lowest value of an array

Tags: kotlin

I want to find the second lowest value in an array and return it, as well as the third, fourth, etc. I managed to find the lowest value with a solution posted here, but I can't find the right syntax to get the second lowest value next, maybe by deleting the lowest value from the variable. This is how I've done it so far:

```
val (minValue, minInt) = Values.zip(Ints).minBy { (_ /* Value not needed */, rating) ->
        rating } ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("Cannot find the minimum of an empty list.")
```

Comment: Do you just want to sort the array?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like what you need is

```
val l = listOf(1,4,6,2,3,6,9)
println(l.sorted().drop(1).take(3))
```

Of course, you can skip as many as you need and take as many as you need.

Answer (score 0):

Call the **sorted()** function and the **subList(fromIndex: Int, toIndex: Int)** on your array.

- **sorted()** function sorts the array in ascending order
- **subList(fromIndex: Int, toIndex: Int)** function returns a portion of the array you need according to the fromIndex and toIndex values you provide.

You can test this with the code snipped below.

```
val list = arrayOf(1,5,6,4,2,6,7,8)
println(list.sorted().subList(1, 4))

Output : [2, 4, 5]
```